# Generic method with lightweight Objective-C generics

Tags: objective-c, generics

I have a generic HTTP request type:

```
@interface Request: NSObject

- (id) parseResponseData: (NSData *) data;

@end
```

I can annotate that to get some generics support:

```
@interface Request<__covariant T>

- (T) parseResponseData: (NSData *) data;

@end
```

Now Xcode correctly suggest the particular return types:

```
Request<NSString*> *request = [Request new];
NSNumber *bar = [request parseResponseData:nil]; // I get a warning, nice!
```

I also have a `Webservice` class that loads a `Request` and returns a nullable instance of `T`:

```
@interface Webservice

- (id) loadSynchronously: (Request *) request;

@end
```

Is there a way to express, in Objective-C, that loading a `Request<Foo*>` returns a `Foo*` and not `id`?

The best I came up with was inverting the call:

```
@interface Request<__covariant T>: NSObject

- (T) parseResponseData: (NSData *) data;
- (T) loadWithWebservice: (Webservice *) ws;

@end
```

Which is an interesting hack, but not a good API. Maybe there’s a similar hack lurking somewhere that would work better?

Comment: I believe that `WebService` will have to be a generic too since Obj-C does not allow generic methods.

Comment: It can not, at least the way I understand it. There is a particular type associated with each `Request` instance, but there is no particular type to be associated with a `Webservice` instance?

Comment: You are trying to write a generic method which is something Obj-C doesn't support.

Comment: The best solution is to start using Swift, even only for some classes. Obj-C is too lenient with types and lightweight generics are there mainly to support Swift therefore they cannot be used for complex cases.

Comment: If I could I would do just that in a wink, but I have to support an older Objective-C codebase.